# vue.js :selected doesn't triggering @change event select/option

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, html-select

I have prop "cat"

```
props: ['cat1'],
```

Ant this piece of code

```
<select class="form-control" @change="set_category">
   <option value="" disabled>Please select category</option>

   <option v-for="category in categories"
          :value="category" 
          :selected="cat1 == category.url">{{ category.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

So this code is called when page its loading and the problem is, that after loading the page option changes but it doesn't triggers @change event, ant because of it i can't actually track which option was selected on page load.
I tried alot versions with v-model ant etc but it sees i just stuck on it..

Comment: So you want to change `cat1` when the user selects an option?

Comment: Can you show the set_category method please?

Comment: @RichardMatsen
set_category method for the moment have only console.log('test') for debuging

What i want to do, when page loads this code its called in the prop cat1 i have part of the url and in the :value="category" i actually have whole object... because cat1 comes from back-end i actually wanna to check if they equal to each other, I mean url from category object (category.url) and url from the prop "cat1". And it they are.. then i want to bind it via set_category method or using any other approach...

Comment: Sorry no luck. The only option I can see is to bind select to cat1 with v-model, then set a watch on cat1 that calls set_category.

Answer (score 1):

[Richard Matsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46388276/657595) is great. But if you only want to track value on page load, why not just call it on `created` (or `mounted`).

```js
created() {
  this.set_category();
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6prmk/hjd198dh/1/):

Answer (score 0):

Here's a directive that will emit the change event as required

```
Vue.directive('binding-change', {
  update: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    const model = vnode.data.directives.find(d => d.name === 'model')
    if (model) {
      binding.value(model.value)
    }
  }
})
```

Use it like this

```
<select class="form-control" v-binding-change="set_category" v-model="cat1">
   <option value="" disabled>Please select category</option>
   <option v-for="(category, index) in categories"
      :key="index"
      :value="category" 
   </option>
</select>

methods: {
  set_category (newValue) {
  }
}
```

I haven't tried it with a prop (just a local variable), but I can say it emits the change event when the bound variable is changed in the background (unlike @change).