# Is it possible to detect if a change event was triggered by a click on a Vue select element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `<select>`-element that has a data property bound to it using `v-model` in Vue.

Sometimes I want to change that value dynamically. I also have an event-listener attached to this element which is triggered on the `change`-event. See code example:

```
<template>
  <div class="mySelector">
        <select id="testSelect" v-model="mySelectModel"
                @change="onChange($event)">
          <template v-for="(item, index) in someList">
              <option :class="['btn', 'btn-default', 'removing-button']" :value="index">{{item.name}}</option>
          </template>
        </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        mySelectModel: null
      }
    },
    props: {
    },
    methods: {
      customChange: function() {
        this.mySelectModel = ... // some value we from somewhere else that is set dynamically on some condiftion
      },
      onChange: function (event) {
        if (!event) return;
        // DO SOMETHING THAT WE ONLY WANT TO DO ON A REAL CLICK
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

The problem I have is that when I change the data value `mySelectModel` dynamically, like in the `customChange`-method, the `change` event is also called, triggering the method `onChange`. I only want to do stuff in that method if it was really triggered by a real click, not when it was changed dynamically.

I can not find a way to distinguish between those cases when the `change`-event is triggered by a click or when it is just changed for some other reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `change` event shouldn't be called if the property used as the `v-model` changes. See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gpedcsr4/1/. Can you show an example of that happening?

Answer (score 0):

See [vue-js-selected-doesnt-triggering-change-event-select-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386061/vue-js-selected-doesnt-triggering-change-event-select-option), it appears that select does not trigger @change when v-model is updated by JS (only when the selected value is changed by user).

A directive can add the functionality

```
Vue.directive('binding-change', {
  update: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    const model = vnode.data.directives.find(d => d.name === 'model')
    if (model) {
      binding.value(model.value)
    }
  }
})
```

use like

```
<select id="testSelect" 
  v-binding-change="onChange" 
  v-model="mySelectModel" 
  @change="onChange($event)">
```

Not sure about the parameter to onChange - I'll give it a test.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414235/392102), you can make a settable computed that you `v-model` in your widget:

1. The `get` function simply returns the data item
2. The `set` function does whatever you want a change in the widget to do, in addition to setting the data item

Other code can change the data item directly and will not execute the `set` code of the computed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    values: ['one','two','three'],
    selectedItem: 'two'
  },
  computed: {
    wrappedSelectedItem: {
      get() { return this.selectedItem; },
      set(value) {
        console.log("Changed in widget");
        this.selectedItem = value;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeToThree() {
      console.log("Stealth change!");
      this.selectedItem = 'three';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="wrappedSelectedItem">
    <option v-for="value in values" :value="value">{{value}}</option>
  </select>
  <button @click="changeToThree">Set to three</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution but it does not  fully work for me. If I do like your example and have a button that changes the value, the `set`-method is not called which is correct. BUT when I change the value from some other method which  is called upon some change on a reactive-variable, the the `set`-method is called anyway. I cant understand the difference.

Comment: It's all a matter of which variable you change. If you change `wrappedSelectedItem`, the setter will be called. If you change `selectedItem`, it will not.

Comment: I am not changing `wrappedSelectedItem`. I am changing `selectedItem` and the setter is called anyway.

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle?